# What's the difference between these two enum declarations - C?

Tags: c, enums, declaration

I've started learning C and have reached the point of enums. An enum is basically a preferred alternative to `DEFINE` / `const int`, correct?

What's the difference between these two declarations?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// method 1
enum days {
    Monday,
    Tuesday
};

int main()
{
    // method 1
    enum days today;
    enum days tomorrow;

    today    = Monday;
    tomorrow = Tuesday;

    if (today < tomorrow)
        printf("yes\n");

    // method 2
    enum {Monday, Tuesday} days;

    days = Tuesday;
    printf("%d\n", days);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enumeration should be preferred over `#define`/`const int` when you want to declare variables that can only take on values out of a limited range of *related*, *mutually exclusive* values.  So the days of the week is a *good* example, but this would be a *bad* example:

```
enum AboutMe
{
    myAge = 27,
    myNumberOfLegs = 2,
    myHouseNumber = 54
};
```

Going back to your code example; the first method declares a *type* called `enum days`.  You can use this type to declare as many variables as you like.

The second method declares a *single variable* of type `enum { ... }`.  You cannot declare any other variables of that type.

Comment: What is the second method good for then? If `days = Tuesday`, wouldn't it be easier to write `const int Tuesday = 1` ? Unless I'm using the 'enum variable' incorrectly in my sample code#second method...

Comment: @dan: "Anonymous" enumeration types do still have advantages.  For instance, they tell the reader of your code that the variable is not just "any old integer"; instead, it can only take on one of a specific range of values.  A debugger will typically display the current value of `days` as `Tuesday`, rather than as `1`.

Comment: "instead, it can only take on one of a specific range of values" - This makes sense. Also seems quite useful. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Being a typenut I would write the first as

```
typedef enum { Monday, Tuesday } days_t;
```

and do declaration as

```
days_t day = Tuesday;
```

The second method I find no use for.

Comment: The second example is useful if you only want a *single* variable that can represent days of the week.

Comment: Can also be used when you don't want any values, but do want some enumerated constants without creating a type and thereby giving the false impression that you might use it for variables.

Comment: @Tony: Can you give an example?  Where would you want *enumerated* constants, but without any variables of that type?

Comment: @Oli: I'm not saying it's good practice, but people - particularly from a C background - sometimes use e.g. `enum { Repetitions = 10 };` then loop an `int` up to `Repetitions`: poor man's constant, though better than a `#define`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first case, days is the name of the enumeration.
Therefore you can access the definition by

```
enum days today;
```

enum days = makes clear which enumeration, the one which is named days

today = variable name

In the second case, days is a variable of the unnamed enumeration.

```
enum {Monday, Tuesday} days;
```

enum {Monday, Tuesday} = unnamed enumeration, therefore needs to be defined with the curl brackets {}

days = variable name